# FileNotFoundException in LIUM Speaker Diarization after re-sampling

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to configure LIUM tool for speaker diarization. This question is a follow up of [UnsupportedAudioFileException in LIUM Speaker Diarization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967169/unsupportedaudiofileexception-in-lium-speaker-diarization#)

I have tried re sampling the file using sox and ffmpeg

I am new to any sorts of programming and i have followed all steps described in LIUM quick start guide and the above link. I still get the same error. I think my input file has issues related to header as mentioned by Nikolay Shmyrev in the above link however i have no clue on how to solve it.

My code is as below:

```
java –jar  C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\LIUM_SpkDiarization-8.4.1.jar \ --fInputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_f2.wav--sOutputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_converted_2.seg -–help --doCEClustering
```

Error:

```
10:52.037 SEVERE AudioFeatureSetFa  FileNotFoundException
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JS_MP3FileReader.getAudioFileFormat(JS_MP3FileReader.java:82)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(Unknown Source)
        at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSetFactory.getAudio(AudioFeatureSetFactory.java:162)
        at fr.lium.spkDiarization.libFeature.AudioFeatureSetFactory.MakeFeature(AudioFeatureSetFactory.java:207)
```

The input file is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Fqe9EX5JbgT09BcXpSREd4em8/view?usp=sharing

Input File Name:converted_f2.wav

I have put the command and the full  output of the prompt in a word document at

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Fqe9EX5JbgUUl6THNCZFgxRnM/view?usp=sharing

The inpiut file has correct sampling rate and other parameters and thus i am not able to understand the cause of the error. 
Thanks a lot for the help

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: The audio sample rate 4000 Hz is indeed unsupported, you need 8000 or 16000 Hz. You need to return to the original file and try to convert it properly.

Comment: Thanks . I loaded the wrong file. The correct file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Fqe9EX5JbgT09BcXpSREd4em8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I used ffmpeg to convert the file. Using ffmpeg the characteristics of the new file are                                                                                      Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'converted_f2.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.48.103
  Duration: 00:07:57.22, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s

Comment: Second file with _f2 is correct, you need to fix the command line then too to use the second file and it will work.

Comment: Still did not work and got the same error. In the command line apart from using the second file what else needs to be fixed?

Comment: Provide the command and the complete output.

Comment: I have put the command and the output of the prompt in a word document at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Fqe9EX5JbgUUl6THNCZFgxRnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Update the question instead

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. I am new to stack oveflow , so thanks for helping me understand how this site works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File not found exception means the file is missing. Indeed you lack a space here:

```
--fInputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_f2.wav--sOutputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_converted_2.seg
```

You need a space before `--sOutputMask`

```
--fInputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_f2.wav  --sOutputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_converted_2.seg
```

Otherwise it looks for a file called 
`C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_f2.wav--sOutputMask= C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\converted_converted_2.seg` which is obviously missing.

Overall, if computer says you that file is missing, it is really missing and you need to search for a reason. Most likely reason is your incorrect input.

Comment: This helped as lot @Nikolay Shmyrev. Instead of giving the full path of the file, i made Desktop as my home directory. Also, there was an extra space in front of the input file as well. Thanks a lot for your help!!!